# Determine the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology

Consider the unit disk $D^2$ and consider the application f: $D^2 \to D^2$, f(x,y)=(-x,-y). Prove that by identifying the border of $D^2$ in the usual way f induces a continuous map $\bar{f}: \mathbf{RP}^2 \to \mathbf{RP}^2$, where $\mathbf{RP}^2$ indicates real projective plane.
Determine the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group $\bar{f}_\ast:\pi_1(\mathbf{RP}^2,x_0) \to \pi_1(\mathbf{RP}^2,x_0) $. I showed the first part, but I don't know how to determine the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give you three hints.

First show that $\bar f$ is actually a homeomorphism. It follows that the induced homomorphism $\bar f_*$ is an automorphism of the group $\pi_1(\mathbf{RP}^2,x_0)$.

Second, do you know what familiar group the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbf{RP}^2,x_0)$ is isomorphic to?

Third, can you figure out how many automorphisms that group has?

Comment: I don't understand the second hint. can you explain better to me?

Comment: what means to determine the homomorphism induced on the fundamental group?

Comment: To determine a function means to give a formula for a function.

Comment: Can you do an example of how to determine this homomorphism induced?

Comment: I think it is necessary to do the "Second" step first.

Comment: I don't understand sorry

Comment: I think, then, that your question requires some preliminary research on your part, in order to learn how to compute the fundamental group $\pi_1(\mathbf{RP}^2,x_0)$.

Comment: I know to compute the fundamental group of $\mathbf{RP^2}$. It is $Z_2$. Then how have I to determine the homomorfism induced?

Comment: Yes, that's right. As said in my answer, there is an induced *auto*morphism $Z_2 \mapsto Z_2$. Can you figure out how many such automorphisms exist?

Comment: No, I can't, sorry.

Comment: Could you say me how have to determine this homomorphism?